# How to manage input validation and Value State in UI5

Tags: xml, validation, sapui5, sap-fiori

I need a help in following scenario. I have a input field and 3 checkboxes infront of it. Requirement is - If user enters something in field, he must check one of the checkboxes. While it gives proper value state in the input field, if I click on Submit button, it does not stop on the page. Rather submit action is a completed successfully. I do not want user to submit successfully if the input is in error state. What should I do? I added the following:

```
XML View:
<Input id="input" width="25px" change="handleChange" </Input>
<CheckBox id="2" text ="Hello" select="ChkSel"> </CheckBox>
<CheckBox id="3" text ="Hello2" select="ChkSel"> </CheckBox>
<CheckBox id="4" text ="Hello3" select="ChkSel"> </CheckBox>

Controller:
    handleChange: function(oEvent) {
            var newValue = oEvent.getParameter("value");
            var check1 = this.getView().byId("2").getSelected();
            var check2 = this.getView().byId("3").getSelected();
            var check3 = this.getView().byId("4").getSelected();

            if (newValue !== "") {
                if (!check1 && !check2 && !check3) {
                                        this.getView().byId("input").setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
                    MessageToast.show("Select appropriate checkbox");
                }
            }
            if (newValue === "") {
                if (check1 || check2 || check3) {
                   MessageToast.show("Enter text or deselect checkbox");
                } 

            }

        },
        ChkSel: function(oEvent) {
            var newValue = this.getView().byId("input").getValue();
            var check1 = this.getView().byId("2").getSelected();
            var check2 = this.getView().byId("3").getSelected();
            var check3 = this.getView().byId("4").getSelected();
            if (newValue !== "") {
                if (check1 || check2 || check3) {
                    this.getView().byId("input").setValueState("None");
                } else {
                    this.getView().byId("input").setValueState(sap.ui.core.ValueState.Error);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just use a different variable that decides for me whether the POST call has to be done or not.

For example, before checking the Value State using a Jquery loop/ JS loop, you can declare a variable `var canProceed=true`.

Now while looping in case you get any id's whose value state is wrong, then you can just update `canProceed = false`, and break the loop.

So if canProceed is true, then do the post request, else show a messagebox, or change value states.